# Paperclip / Passenger NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, paperclip

When I try to upload a photo in [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) using [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) on my local machine it works perfectly.

When I try to upload a photo in Ruby on Rails using Paperclip on our Linux ([CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 5.2) server with Apache and [Phusion Passenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phusion_Passenger), I get:

```
2 errors prohibited this user from being saved
There were problems with the following fields:
- Avatar /tmp/stream20091026-21120-1qdbnul-0 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
- Avatar /tmp/stream20091026-21120-1qdbnul-0 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

I tried adding:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

to production.rb but it didn't make a difference.

In the log files I get the following errors:

> Parameters: {"commit"=>"Upload",
>   "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"419410afc22737cd2f6b6096a95327db76a48ba9",
>   "controller"=>"users",
>   "user"=>{"avatar"=>#}}
>   [paperclip] Saving attachments.
>   [paperclip] An error was received
>   while processing:
>
> /tmp/stream20091026-20752-1g568yk-0 is
>   not recognized by the 'identify'
>   command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identify is a command-line utility inside the [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) package.

From its homepage:

> The identify program describes the
> format and characteristics of one or
> more image files. It also reports if
> an image is incomplete or corrupt. The
> information returned includes the
> image number, the file name, the width
> and height of the image, whether the
> image is colormapped or not, the
> number of colors in the image, the
> number of bytes in the image, the
> format of the image (JPEG, PNM, etc.),
> and finally the number of seconds it
> took to read and process the image.
> Many more attributes are available
> with the verbose option.

First, copy the image on the server and run the identify command on it. You should receive something like:

```
identify ~/capture.jpg 
capture.jpg JPEG 1216x244 1216x244+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 97.7kb
```

If you receive an error, try upgrading the ImageMagick package on your server. You may find an updated binary release here:
[http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Comment: After a lot of messing about I managed to work out that the libraries for .jpeg .png were not install on our linux production server, but they are installed on my imac. So I had to download those libraries and install them and then reinstall imagemagick (not helped by the fact imagemagick.org has been down all afternoon :( )

Answer (score 0):

in my case with same error, reinstalling imagemagic helped out (ubuntu 12.10)